# Why does JavaScript Array.push not use variable if the pushed element is not a primitive

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, for-loop, closures

Consider this classic JavaScript closure function. I understand how the closure is exhibited. I understand that the inner function closes in on the variable i, which is 3.

What I dont understand is why the array should contain the variable i, when all we are doing is pushing a function into an array where i has a value from the for loop.

```js
function buildFunctions() {

  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(function() {
      console.log(i)
    })
  }
  return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunctions(); // [function(){console.log(1)}, ...and so on]
//not [function(){console.log(i)} ...and so on]

fs[0](); // outputs 3
fs[1](); // 3
fs[2](); // 3
```

otherwise, this would return the correct(imo) contents of the array:

```
function buildFunctions() {
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      arr.push(i)
   }
   return arr; // [0, 1, 2]
 }
```

Comment: The variable `i` is *shared* by all of the functions your code creates. At the end of the loop, the value of `i` is 3, so that's what you get when you call the functions.

Comment: Use `for (let i=0...`, it works, because it creates a local scope for `i`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `i` refers to the index of the array and is required to use the `for-loop`. In your first example, the array contains three functions, in your second example, it contains three numbers. You could omit the loop and just write `arr.push(0); arr.push(1); arr.push(2);` .

Comment: I know this, @Pointy, the for loop is pushing a function that should be having a value, 0, 1 & then 2. Like that last function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @Shilly why doesnt console.log(i) not pushed into the array with its value though?

Comment: @fatahn — Because there is no reason for the value to be stored in the array.

Comment: It logs a _reference_ to `i`, not its _value_ at the moment it's pushed. All three references are the same.

Comment: Because you push a function, not the result of a function. What you say would only work if the code is like this: `arr.push(function(){return i;}());` Then you would create a function, immediately call it and add the returned value of i to the array instead of the function itsself. Console.log() does Not return anything, it only logs to the console. So it will never return its result to the array. It sounds a bit like you're mixing up closures, immediately invoked functions and return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr.push(i)` passes a primitive value to `.push`, the values `0`, `1` and `2` respectively. The value becomes disassociated from `i` here; you're not pushing `i`, you're pushing `0`, `1` and `2`.

`arr.push(function () { console.log(i) })` pushes a function, which internally references a variable. At the time that you call the function, the value of that variable happens to be `3`. <sub>( This is the critical sentence to understand.)</sub>

Note that there's no fundamental difference between pushing a function and pushing a number. Both are simply passed by value. Just in one case the value is a number and in the other case the value is a function. See [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/476).

Comment: I almost flagged this question as duplicate of the closures question but realized its different, thanks for that critical bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think the loop adds confusion for some reason. If you unroll that loop, it likely is more intuitive.

```js
function buildFunctions() {

  var arr = [];
  var i = 0;

  arr.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })

  i++;

  arr.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })

  i++;

  arr.push(function() {
    console.log(i)
  })

  i++;
  
  return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunctions(); // [function(){console.log(1)}, ...and so on]
//not [function(){console.log(i)} ...and so on]

fs[0](); // outputs 3
fs[1](); // 3
fs[2](); // 3
```

So you can see that we're pushing three functions into the array, and in between, we're incrementing `i`. You can also see that all three functions are "looking at" the same `i` variable.

The variable *is not read until the function is invoked*, so because they're all "looking at" the same variable, they're naturally going to give the same result when finally invoked. And because the `i` was incremented three times *before any of the invocations*, the value returned will be `3`.

---

As an exercise, change each function to add another `i++` within. You'll see that no only are they all *reading* the same variable, but they all can *mutate* that same variable too.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks. Is it correct to say that, before the function call, the contents of the array inside the function are: `[fn(){console.log(0)}, fn(){console.log(0)}, fn(){console.log(2)}]` while the scope context still exists?

Comment: Not really. That would imply that the values of `i` are copied into the functions. Instead the functions only have the ability to reference `i`, so it would be more like `[fn(){console.log(i)}, fn(){console.log(i)}, fn(){console.log(i)}]` So when each function is invoked, it uses that `i` reference to read the *current* value of `i`.

Comment: ...the scope of the `buildFunctions` call will *continue to exist* as long as at least one of those functions that points to `i` continues to exist.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you call the function the value of `i` becomes `3` which the function inside `arr.push` refer.

Block scope `let` will give you the expected result:

```js
function buildFunctions() {

   var arr = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
       arr.push(function() { 
          console.log(i)
       }) 
   }
   return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunctions(); // [function(){console.log(1)}, ...and so on]
                           //not [function(){console.log(i)} ...and so on]

fs[0](); // 0
fs[1](); // 1
fs[2](); // 2
```

Comment: That further raises the question *why?* It doesn't really answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

> What I dont understand is why the array should contain the variable i

It doesn't.

The array contains three functions.

Each of those functions closes over the (same) variable `i`. Note: `i` not *the value of `i`* at the time.

**When** you call any of the functions (which is **after the loop has finished**), they read the value of that variable.